# Creating a 3d Graph with Matplotlib using Excel with Multiple Columns Grouped on one Axis

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, matplotlib, 3d

I am working in Python and trying to create a 3dimensional chart that shows 3 different things on each axis: Product(categorized by type and system) on the x, revenue on the y, and country/region on the z.  Here is the code I am working with right now:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from matplotlib import cm 
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')

#import file 
data_file = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/cbunce/Desktop/Product Revenue Analysis.xlsx')


#print data_file 
    #prints entire file properly 


#read columns
Location = data_file['Location']
System = data_file['System Platform']
Product = data_file['Product Grouping']
Sub_Group = data_file['Sub-Group']
Revenue = data_file['2016_Revenue ']


x = Product, Sub_Group
y = Location
z = Revenue
#print axes
    #prints axes as 

dx = .5 * np.ones
dy = dx.copy()
dz = data.flatten()


ax1.bar3d(x,y,z,dx,dy,dz)


ax1.set_xlabel('Product Group')
ax1.set_ylabel('Country')
ax1.set_zlabel('Revenue')

plt.plot(x,y,z)
plt.show()
```

Here is the kind of graph I want to get, but python makes it more user friendly for a large amount of data:

[image]

Also,

Here is my data(example):

```
Location System Platform Product Grouping Sub-Group Base Material 2016_Revenue  
United States   GTR             Accessory   Fast    12345    $45,000,000 
China           GTR             Accessory   Fast    12346    $43,000,000 
United States   GTR             Device      Run     12347    $8,000,000 
United States   Beta            Device      Fast    12348    $6,500,000 
Taiwan          Alpha           Accessory   Walk    12349    $4,300,000 
North Korea     Alpha           Camera      Run     12310    $3,200,000 
Taiwan          GTR             Camera      Fast    12311    $2,800,000 
Japan           GTR             Accessory   Fast    12312    $2,400,000 
China           Alpha           Accessory   Car     12313    $1,700,000
```

Appreciate any help!!!

Comment: So what exactly is the problem that you're having with your current code?

Comment: So the graph I have displayed is from Excel, however I am trying to plot a lot of data and want it to be an interactive graph where you can scroll and drag and whatnot.  I cannot figure out how to have my axes show the text data in groups (or at all for that matter...  I just want the same graph from the excel picture in matplotlib so that I can scroll around and stuff

Comment: @Xukrao sorry I did not tag you